# Thermodynamics identities of magnetic materials

Tags: electromagnetism, thermodynamics

According to the chapter 2 of Yeosman, Statistical mechanics of phase transitions,

$dU = T\ dS - M\ dH$ if we consider the energy of magnetic dipole

but

$dU = T\ dS + H\ dM$ if we consider the energy of magnetic dipole and the energy associated with the magnetic field of the dipole

How do we derive the second expression of $dU$?

Answer (score 1):

The two $U$-s are not the same. Probably $dU = TdS + HdM$ is a "better" form because this way $U(S,M)$ depends on extensive variables $S$ and $M$ and this is consistent with most conventional definitions of the thermodynamic internal energy. A Legendre transform, similar to the one used to define enthalpy, will change this $U$ into a new $U'(S,H) = U - HM$, because now $dU'=TdS + HdM - HdM - MdH = TdS- MdH$, as you have written it. This $U'$ is akin to enthalpy, it depends on extensive $S$ and on an intensive $H$ parameter, just as enthalpy depends on $S$ and on $p$. In experimental work it is easier to control the intensive parameter pressure $p$ for enthalpy than volume for the internal energy $U$, and similarly the field $H$ as generated by an external current of a solenoid, say, for this $U'$ than magnetization $M$ for $U$.